# Checkboxes taking 100% of the width

Tags: html, css

I want 100% input size for other inputs but not checkboxes, so I put inline `max-width` for checkbox. But it won't work.

```css
#application-form label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#application-form input,
#application-form select {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="checkbox-agree" required style="max-width: 3%">
  <span style="float: left;">I have read and agree to the Credit Guide & Quote and the Privacy Policy & Consent</span>
</label>
```

Here is [live](http://testwebsitepage.club/application/) version.

Comment: assign a class checkbox to the input of type checkbox and use a `#application-form input .checkbox` selector?

Comment: You cannot style checkboxes in that manner. It's just not possible.
Check https://gist.github.com/Loupax/f57b3f7fe48f3514903939ab7356bb67 for possible solution

Comment: What browser are you looking at. I checked in FF and chrome, both look normal

Comment: @Huangism I checked in those 2 and doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Loupax I tried that `input[type=checkbox] ` as well, didn't work. Live version link included in question, just edited..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do not select the checkbox when applying styles to your input. I also added the application-form id so the checkbox actually looks 100% if you do not have the not and I removed your inline css. The key line is

`#application-form input:not([type=checkbox])`

Docs are here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

> The :not() CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a
>   list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being
>   selected, it is known as the negation pseudo-class.

```css
#application-form label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#application-form input:not([type=checkbox]),
#application-form select {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="application-form">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="checkbox-agree" required>
    <span style="float: left;">I have read and agree to the Credit Guide & Quote and the Privacy Policy & Consent</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```html
<label style="display:inline;"> <input id="checkbox-agree" style="display:inline-block" name="agree" required="" type="checkbox" /> <span style="display:inline-block;width:50%;vertical-align:top;">I have read and agree to the Credit Guide &amp; Quote and the Privacy Policy &amp; Consent</span> </label>
```

Suggestion - Use a `class` or `ID` to add CSS. Avoid using inline CSS :-)

Answer (score 0):

you could use flexboxes

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<label>
 <span >I have read and agree to the Credit Guide & Quote and the Privacy Policy & Consent</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="checkbox-agree" required>
</label>
```